# Order/sort collection after mapping values

Tags: rethinkdb

I want to sort my results by the new values I obtain after using .map(). How is this manageable? I have consulted the API without any luck.

In my example I have prices of different currencies stored in a database, but I want to get them ordered by price after applying the day-to-day exchange rate.

Here is my ReQL query:

```
r.table('price_variants')
  .orderBy({index: 'price'})
  .filter({'productID': product('id'), 'currentlyUsed': true})
  .limit(1)
  .map(function(variant) {
    variant = variant.merge({
      price: r.branch(
        variant
          .hasFields('exchange_type')
            .and(variant('exchange_type')
            .eq('EURUSD')),                       //IF EUR
        variant('price').mul(exchangeRateUSDEUR), //THEN convert to USD
        variant('price')),                        //ELSE just use original price
      ) 
    })
  })
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Sorting your results, before or after a map, can be done with `orderBy`. For example:

```
r.table('foo')
 .map(function(foo){
     return foo.merge({c: foo('a').add(foo('b'))});
 })
 .orderBy('c')
```

However, your specific example has a few issues you might have to fix first.

- Sorting seems pointless because it only has one document (because of `.limit(1)`)
- Your mapped function doesn't return anything.